# Message not delivering to Client in Java

Tags: java, client-server, server, lan

I have a Server-Client program in Java where,in my Server UI I have two `JLabel`,when I Click on my 1st `JLabel` message is going to 1st Client but when I click it again message is not going to the client. Can someone point me out whats the mistake in my code?

//SERVER CODE

```
 void connect_clients()
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton1.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                while (true) {

                    socket = listener.accept();
                    try {
                            clientIP = socket.getLocalAddress().getHostName();
                        }    
                    catch(Exception e){}
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

            }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
        }
    }
}                                    

private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    PrintWriter out;
     try {
         out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.println("pc2");
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(third_frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

//client code

```
 void connect_server()
    {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
                            "running the date service on port 9090:");
            s = new Socket(serverAddress, 7700);


            BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String answer = input.readLine();

            System.out.println(answer);
            answer = null;

        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(client_form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: `Socket` is declared globally in both Server and Client.

Comment: Oh god that formatting... Could you please format your server code better?

Comment: Your message about port `9090` should read `7700` I suspect.

Comment: I suggest you separate your network handling code from your GUI handling code and also test them separately.  When you combine them and there is an issue it makes it very hard to work out which is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @PeterLawre, thats just a typo,the port is same in  both server and client.

Comment: @AnubianNoob,i formatted my code,hope u get it now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i dont get you. what do u mean by separating etwork and ui code?

Comment: @question have classes just for network handling code which you test would by themselves without any gui code involved. This way you can be sure whether the network code works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client code doesnt have a loop.

On String answer = input.readLine(); the client waits for the message to receive. Once it receives the text from server the clients execution is done.

Client is not written to receive all the message from server.

So if you look back the Server-Client paradigm, the server listens to the port actively and once the client requests something from server. It process the request.

On the other hand , Client doesnt have to listen actively on whats going on at the server which contradicts the fundamental idea of why Client exist.

Comment: So u suggest me to put a infinite loop in client method?

Comment: Thanks this worked. But there is another problem here the messages are going only to the last client connected. For example if 5 client are connected only to the 5th client message is going.

Comment: Have a string name status. On clicking labels change only the status values. When a client requests send the status value to the client.                            Asking client to monitor the Server by pinging infinitely will load up ur server based on how the request is processed.

Comment: can u give me a example on how to implement this logic?